# How to get a row with left join with two right table row matching two separate value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get Ronald from Left Table through matching Right Table values with 1 AND 2. I know I need to use DISTINCT to get only one row but other than that, I'm stumped.

Left Table

```
pid | name
1     Ronald
2     Chris
3     John
```

Right Table

```
pid | value
1     1
1     2
2     1
3     2
```

Joined Table

```
pid | name   | value
1     Ronald   1
1     Ronald   2
2     Chris    1
3     John     2
```

Expected Output

```
pid | name
1     Ronald
```

Comment: Please include the exact SQL command you ran

Answer (score 0):

You want to match both 1 and 2.  Aggregation and `having` come to mind:

```
select t1.pid, t1.name
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.pid = t2.pid
where t2.value in (1, 2)
group by t1.pid, t1.name
having count(*) = 2;  -- should be `count(distinct)` if duplicates are possible in `table2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Self join table2 and select value = 1 in the first and value = 2 in the second. Join the result with table 1.

```
select t1.pid, t1.name
from table1 t1
join table2 t2_1 on t1.pid = t2_1.pid 
join table2 t2_2 on t2_1.pid = t2_2.pid AND t2_1.value = 1 AND t2_2.value = 2
```

Or if you like that better:

```
select t1.pid, t1.name
from table1 t1
join table2 t2_1 on t1.pid = t2_1.pid AND t2_1.value = 1
join table2 t2_2 on t2_1.pid = t2_2.pid AND t2_2.value = 2
```